# Set UILocalNotification on a response from the server in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have multiple images which I sent to the server and get response after successful upload response 1.

Now I want to set a local notification on it, that if server response 1 after upload of an image it should show a notification like a banner that Image is sent.

I have tried some code but it is showing any alert when I get the response.

My code is:

```
    -(void)Images{

            NSString *eachImagePath;
            if(_arrai.count == 0)
                return;

            eachImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_arrai[0]];

            NSMutableDictionary *dictAddNewJobImages = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            dictAddNewJobImages[@"property_id"] = Propid;
            dictAddNewJobImages[@"name"] = _arrainame;

            NSString *strWebService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My URL"];

            AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
            manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

            [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:600.0];

             [manager POST:strWebService parameters:dictAddNewJobImages constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData)
             {
                 NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:eachImagePath];
                 [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
             } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
             {
             } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                 [_arrai removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                 if(_arrai.count > 0)
                     [self Images];


             } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",error);

              }];

            NSString *res = [serverResponse valueForKey:@"response"];
            NSLog(@"response: %@", res);

            UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

           // localNotification.fireDate = res;

            localNotification.alertBody = res;

            localNotification.alertAction = @"Image Sent";

            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication 

        sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

            // Request to reload table view data
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

            // Dismiss the view controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: FWIW It's better to use the newer [`UNUserNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework. See [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250) tutorial.

Comment: the link  u provide is in swift , i'm working on objective c @Honey

Comment: 1. The logic is 100% the same 2. my point is, try using the latest framework. Because your code my suddenly just not work in some iOS 10.x version or with iOS 11 version...

Comment: only i have to use the framework? My code looks correct?@Honey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please add notification like this:**

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];


UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

            localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];

            localNotification.alertBody = res;

            localNotification.alertTitle = @"Image Sent";

            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication 

        sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: @Oneeb add this :             localNotification.alertTitle = @"Image Sent";
check my updated answer

Comment: Bro it asked me the permission to Allow the notification but i haven't seen any alert in my simulator. @SaurabhJain

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: @Oneeb Please try this in real device.

Comment: Bro , i have test on a real device it only ask permission but when it upload the image it does not show any alert of image sent. @Saurabh Jain

Comment: it is showing this there Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <SubmitDetailsViewController: 0x1018ce600>. @SaurabhJain

Comment: your means local notification not fired @Oneeb

Comment: Try it in the background. @Oneeb

Comment: Yes notification fired , where in the background? In Appdelegate.m file? same code? @SaurabhJain

Comment: @Oneeb -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    //Called when notification is delivered to a foreground app.
} use this method

Comment: Where to write this method in same view controller or in App delegate.m file? @SaruabhJain

Comment: Write in appdelegate.m @Oneeb

Comment: getting error there that unknown type. @Saurabh Jain

Comment: how to call it in a foreground? @Saruabh Jain

Comment: what to write in in calling the notification. @SaurabhJain

Comment: Bro, i'm stuck there can u explain what to write in a calling a notification? @SaurabhJain

Comment: @Oneeb Please see this tutorial https://ios-tutor.blogspot.in/2014/11/local-notification-in-ios8.html, https://www.devfright.com/uilocalnotification-tutorial/

Comment: This tutorial will help you after that have you any problem please talk to me @Oneeb